# How get albums pictures, friends count by Facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook graph SDK to access facebook user's album pictures, profile picture, friends count and other basic information of user. But it is doing strange things, it is showing albums of only of API account owner's account, instead of showing of any user login by facebook.
I am using following code, please someone help me and guide where I am going wrong.
Thank you very much.

```
include_once(BASE_DIR.'/utils/facebook/autoload.php');
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
  'app_id' => $fb_app_id,
  'app_secret' => $fb_app_secret,

));

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
foreach ($_SESSION as $k=>$v) {                    
    if(strpos($k, "FBRLH_")!==FALSE) {
        if(!setcookie($k, $v)) {

        } else {
            $_COOKIE[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
}
$permissions = array('email', 'user_photos', 'user_friends', 'read_custom_friendlists', 'user_status');
$loginUrl = htmlspecialchars($helper->getLoginUrl(SITE_URL . '/sign-up.php?do=fb', $permissions));
$_SESSION['fui'] = array();
foreach ($_COOKIE as $k=>$v) {
    if(strpos($k, "FBRLH_")!==FALSE) {
        $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
    }
}

if( isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'fb' ){
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $k=>$v) {
        if(strpos($k, "FBRLH_")!==FALSE) {
            $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,albums', $accessToken);
        $fb_user_info = $response->getGraphUser();
        $fb_first_name = $fb_user_info->getProperty('first_name');
        $fb_last_name = $fb_user_info->getProperty('last_name');
        $fb_user_id = $fb_user_info->getProperty('id');
        $fb_user_email = $fb_user_info->getProperty('email');
        $albums = $fb->get('/me/albums', $accessToken)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
        $user_friends = $fb->get('/me/friends?fields=id,name,gender', $accessToken)->getGraphEdge();
        $user_fb_photos = array();
        foreach( $albums as $album_id => $album_data ){
            $user_fb_photos[$album_data['id']]['name'] = $album_data['name'];
            $fbPictures = $fb->get("/".$album_data['id']."/photos?fields=picture&limit=12", $accessToken)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
            $user_fb_photos[$album_data['id']]['data'] = $fbPictures;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: of course it only shows the albums of the authorized user. what else do you expect to get? check out the api reference in the facebook docs, they explain very well what data you get for which endpoint.

Comment: User is logging by facebook API, and giving authentication to access his photos, but it is working only for API owner, not other users those login by facebook api

Answer (score 0):

Read about Login Review in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Most permissions only work for users with a role in the App. If you want to go public with your App, you have to send those permission in for review. You should actually get a very visible red warning about that when authorizing with an App Admin/Developer.